# read data using shared preferences, data always re-render in flutter

Tags: flutter

I tried to read data using shared preferences and return my widget using FutureBuilder, but the problem is... when I click another tab screen and then back again to my home tab screen, the data inside widget always rerender.. is there a way so that my data always stick in my widget whenever I click another tab and back again to my home tab?
here is the code

```
class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<SecondPage> {
  Future<int> _getUsername;

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getUsername = SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
      return prefs.getInt("username");
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _getUsername,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
            print("loading");
            return Text("Loading username...");
// how to prevent this condition so that my data always stick in my widget without rerender
          }

          final username = snapshot.data.toString();

          return Container(
            child: Text("Hello $username"),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`

code snippet

```
class _Page3State extends State<Page3>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<Page3> {
  ...

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

 FutureBuilder(
        future: _getUsername,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
            print("loading");
            return Text("Loading username...");
```

Working demo, you can see console output only print one `loading`

[image]

Output

```
I/flutter ( 8528): loading
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MainPersistentTabBar(),
    );
  }
}

class MainPersistentTabBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 4,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            isScrollable: true,
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car),
                text: "Non persistent",
              ),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit), text: "Persistent"),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_railway), text: "Test 1"),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_subway), text: "Test 2"),
            ],
          ),
          title: Text('Persistent Tab Demo'),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            Page1(),
            Page2(),
            Page3(),
            Text('Page 4'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page3 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page3State createState() => _Page3State();
}

class _Page3State extends State<Page3>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<Page3> {
  Future<int> _getUsername;

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getUsername = SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
      return prefs.getInt("username");
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _getUsername,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
            print("loading");
            return Text("Loading username...");
// how to prevent this condition so that my data always stick in my widget without rerender
          }

          final username = snapshot.data.toString();

          return Container(
            child: Text("Hello $username"),
          );
        });
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page1State createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  var list = List();

  _loadList() async {
    final response =
        await http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          list = json.decode(response.body) as List;
        });
      }
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load posts');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadList();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: list.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        final data = list[index];
        return ListTile(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          title: Text(data['title']),
          subtitle: Text(
            data['body'],
            maxLines: 2,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page2State createState() => _Page2State();
}

class _Page2State extends State<Page2>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<Page2> {
  var list = List();

  _loadList() async {
    final response =
        await http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          list = json.decode(response.body) as List;
        });
      }
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load posts');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadList();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          final data = list[index];
          return ListTile(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            title: Text(data['title']),
            trailing: Image.network(
              data['thumbnailUrl'],
              height: 20.0,
              width: 20.0,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Comment: I try your code but I get an error that say like this ```This method overrides a method annotated as @mustCallSuper in 'AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin', but doesn't invoke the overridden method.``` is there something missing inside ```class _Page3State```?

Comment: wantKeepAlive  , please check code snippet and full code again.

Comment: I have checked it and updated my question with update code, but still I get an error that I have said before, is there something missing here?

Comment: can not reproduce. please post all of your code or related reproduced code.

Comment: I have solved the error by adding ```super.build(context);``` but I still can not prevent ```Loading username``` in my screen ... I still get ```Loading username``` show up in my screen for a second

Comment: it works well like your demo image after I change my bottom tab navigator with your tab, thank you very much for your help :D

Comment: it works well like your demo image after I change my bottom tab navigator with your tab, thank you very much for your help :D